# How to write rspec testing for find_for_facebook_oauth method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    partner = Partner.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if partner
      return partner
    else
      registered_partner = Partner.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_partner
        return registered_partner
      else
        partner = Partner.create(
                    username: "#{auth.info.name.downcase.delete(' ')}_#{Time.now.to_i}",
                    provider: auth.provider,
                    uid: auth.uid,
                    email: auth.info.email,
                    first_name: auth.info.first_name,
                    last_name: auth.info.last_name,
                    password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                    auth_token: auth.credentials.token,
                    user_type: 'partners',
                    oauth_expires_at: Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at).to_datetime
                  )
      end    
    end
    partner
  end
```

Above code is for facebook authentication.

I want to write Rspec Testing for above methods.

I unable to understand how to pass **auth** as argument in the parameters ?

Please help me how can I pass **auth** as argument in testing ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your describe block, create fixture for **auth**, then write your spec that calls the method and pass the fixture **auth** to your method:

```
describe YourClass do
  it "should do certain things" do
    # fixture auth
    fixture_auth = "SomeRandomValue"

    # pass it to your method
    YourClass.find_for_facebook_oauth(fixture_auth)
  end
end
```

Not too sure if that is what you are asking for, but hope it may help